# Mixed Effects Logistic Regression vs Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model

I'm conducting a study on how pregnancy weight gain affects risk of breast cancer and decided to go with a logistic regression model (outcome is yes/no for breast cancer) and my primary independent variable is categorical (<10lbs, 10-19 lbs, 30-39 lbs and >40 lbs each compared to the referent 20-29lbs). I've recently been told that mixed modeling may be a better alternative to account for random effects (which as I understand is basically variation between subjects if I treat that as a random effect for example).

My question is: are there any major drawbacks to using mixed-effects logistic regression? Is it a more complex model by any chance that I may not necessarily need? Could it inflate odds ratios?

In other words, how do I defend my use of logistic regression over mixed-effects logistic regression, if I can?

Comment: Are there known causes of breast cancer that you have no data for?  (eg, smoking & alcohol consumption)

Comment: I have data for most breast cancer risk factors and do plan on including them as covariates in my model. What are your thoughts?

Comment: What would your 'groups' of observations be in a mixed model?  E.g. Do you have multiple measurements per subject?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. The way the data is set up is that the subjects are asked to fill out a questionnaire every 2 years and they're asked if they've been diagnosed with breast cancer, so I suppose those count as repeated measurements?

Comment: You started off on the wrong foot by classifying a continuous variable and pretending that subjects are homogeneous in the <10lbs and >40lbs groups.  This will do more damage to the model than any benefit you will achieve by better modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches of including random effects in your model (random slope model, random slope + intercept model, random intercept model). You can check for the magnitude of random effects using for example "induced correlation" ([Zuur et al. 2008](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387874579)).

Based on its magnitude you can then justify whether to include the random effect in your model or not.

While there is no threshold (at least that I know of) at which to include or exclude a random effect in your model (talking about "induced correlation"), you can most often easily justify the exclusion of random effects with a value close to 0. Furthermore, you have a generalized comparison of the influences of your random effects.

In general, simple models are preferred over complex ones in statistical modelling.